# Accessing and printing Hash of array

Tags: perl, perl-hash

I have a question of how to print a hash:

```
@language(1,2,3);
for my $i (0 .. $#language)
{
  $statement = $db->selectall_arrayref(
    "select word from words
    left outer join language
    on words.languageId = language.languageId
    where words.languageId = $language;"
  );
  %words=((@language[$language])=> {@$statement});
}
return %words;
```

How can help to print out the hash

I tried this:

```
foreach my $key(keys %newwordsList)
{
    print "Dozzzz: " . $key . "\n";

    for my $ind(0 .. @{$newwordsList{$key}}-1){
        print $newwordsList{$key}[$ind] . "\n";
    }
}
```

But I get nothing.

and I have a question: Hash is a sequential order or not
I mean the `$key`, because i try yo print `$keys`
it is supposed to print `123` but it prints out `132`

what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hash tables don't preserve insertion order. You'll need to use a different data structure, perhaps Tie::IxHash.